# Pass by reference php

Tags: php

So im learning about passing by reference, what i dont understand is this, do i need to use pass by reference on functions? Like this

```
$items = [1,2,3,4,5];
function my_func(&$items) {
    $items[] = 6;
}

    
my_func($items);
var_dump($items);
```

It will output

```
array(6) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(5) [5]=> int(6) }
```

I have seen people adding values to array by reference like this

```
class play {
    public function test() {

        $items = [1,2,3,4,5];

        foreach($items as &$item) {
            $item[] = 6;
        }

        return $items;
    }
}

$play = new play;
$play->test();
```

then i get Warning:

> Cannot use a scalar value as an array in

Is there a way in a loop to add a value by reference outside a function?

Comment: The code you show would be used for a 2-dimensional array, because it's adding something to each row. It doesn't make any sense for a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `$item = 6;`, which will replace every element of the array with `6`.

Comment: If you just want to add a new element to the array, and you're not in a function, you don't need to use a reference variable or a loop.

Comment: What is the actual result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function to use reference variables. You can do it with ordinary assignment.

```
$items = [1,2,3,4,5];
$alias = &$items;

$alias[] = 6;
print_r($items);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you misunderstand what the code is doing...

You have an array...

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

...which can be re-written as...

```
$array = [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 4,
    4 => 5,
    5 => 6,
];

// Hint: try print_r($array);
```

...the numbers on the left are the `keys` and the numbers on the right are the `values`.

Your loop loops through the array one *row* at a time:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo $item;
}

// Output: 123456
```

Now, if you add the "pass by reference" operator then you can edit the value of `$item`; for example we could turn each *item* in the array to `1`...

```
foreach ($array as &$item) {
    $item = 1;
}

print_r($array);

/* Output:

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
)

*/
```

Without the `&` in front of `$item` the code above would **only** change the value of `$item` inside of the `foreach` loop. The original array would not be touched.

The reason that you get an error is because you're assigning a value to `$item` as though it were an array. Where as, in fact, the `$item` variable is an integer. So all you need to do to make it work is remove the `[]` in your assignment line:

```
$item[] = 6;

// Becomes...

$item = 6;
```

If, instead of **replacing** a value you want to **add** a value then you can do that. But you need to add a value to the array which is `$items` **NOT** `$item`:

```
$items[] = 6;
```

Of course, doing that in a loop will add the value once for each item in the array...

Comment: I was wondering Steven what do you mean with the last part in your example, could you be so kind and give and code exampel on adding value to the array, i mean this part $items[] = 6, is it not the same as the new code exampel i posted?

Comment: The last part `$items[] = 6` adds a new element to the `$items` array. The reason it's different from your _new code_ is that your new code amends (rather than appends) an entry in the array and your _new code_ is an array as opposed to an integer. If that makes sense?

Comment: Yes i do understand. My old example was not an array therefor it did not add value to the array. This $items[] = 6 adds a value to the array, since it's in a loop it will add to all the items in the array a number 6. But that had nothing to do with the passing by reference, it's hard to create a good question and make everybody understand what one means. My problem i had was that i wanted to add data to a multidimensional array, and people tought i wanted to overwrite data in the array. Im sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JustAOrdinaryMonkey I understand what you intended (having seen your answer) and of course it's tricky - if you knew exactly what you wanted you wouldn't have a question! It isn't a problem. If you had changed the question to `$array = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ];` i.e. a two dimensional array and asked how to update each `$item` (which then would be the second level array) in a `foreach` loop with _passing by reference_ then your answer would make sense and people would have understood. But as it stands multi-dimensional arrays weren't mentioned?

Comment: @JustAOrdinaryMonkey the problem (for this site) is that while the answers to your question hopefully help you they are supposed to be helpful to future readers as well. Currently the question asks about updating a one dimension array (with what looks like some confusion around `$item[]` (which is the syntax for adding an item to an array and why I added the bit on the end). However what you meant to ask was about multidimensional arrays. So updating your question as per my previous comment would make that clear to future readers?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
$result['books'][0] = ['id' => 1];
$result['books'][1] = ['id' => 2];

foreach ($result['books'] as &$book) {   // use a reference
    $book['new_index'] = 'new value';
    $book['new_book_id'] = '29929292';
}
//unset($book); // unset the reference
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Typically if you answer your own question you should mark it as accepted so that future readers with similar problems know what helped you out; however this code is in no way related to the question... You should really amend the question or remove/amend the answer - otherwise neither the question or answer is of any use to future readers